# sending name attribute of form element via curl post

Tags: php, html, curl

I have to send some data which normally comes from an `HTML` form.
there is a *tag* in my `form` which is like

```
<form action='***' name=*** method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset = "UTF-8";
        return checkMandatery()' accept-charset='UTF-8' id="form">
```

how do I set up my `curl-code` to pass the *name-attribute* through it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: onsubmit='return checkMandatery(this.name)'

Comment: hm. sorry if i did not explained right. this form will be replaced with the php-script and then executed periodically by cron. I think this javascript-stuff will not work like that. hope im right.

Comment: hey, I just tried to execute the curl request just without passing this attribute and it worked well. Then I realized it is only needed by the javascript that checks the data typed in by the user. Since I dont need to check it I am happy with that.